# ImportError when importing psycopg2 on M1

Tags: python, psycopg2

Has anyone gotten this error when importing `psycopg2` after successful installation?

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/chrishicks/Desktop/test/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002):
tried: '/Users/chrishicks/Desktop/test/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-39-darwin.so'
(mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture
(have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')),
'/usr/local/lib/_psycopg.cpython-39-darwin.so' (no such file),
'/usr/lib/_psycopg.cpython-39-darwin.so' (no such file)
```

I have tried installing `psycopg2` and `psycopg2-binary` and have tried both while running `iTerm` in Rosetta.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please clarify what operating system you're using.

Comment: How are you installing this? brew or pip? I've just tried to install with pip3 on M1 and works fine!

Comment: Hi @ewong thank you. I am using Monterey 12.2.1

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Using this line should fix it:

```
pip3.9 install psycopg2-binary --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir
```

Comment: Of course! Anything for Hicks LLC!

Comment: no, I still have that error only

Comment: Also, what is the significance of `pip3.9` over any other `pip.3x`?

Answer (score 2):

my fellow had the same issue.
I consoled `pip3.9 install psycopg2-binary --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir` but it didn't work for him.
I helped him to solved it by this way:
firstly, uninstall the `psycopg2-binary`

```
pip uninstall psycopg2-binary
```

Then, install it

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

@hardy