# psycopg2-binary and sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

When I pip install SQLAlchemy, there was an error:

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/michaelgao/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Users/michaelgao/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-39-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/local/lib/_psycopg.cpython-39-darwin.so' (no such file), '/usr/lib/_psycopg.cpython-39-darwin.so' (no such file)

Other stackexchange articles ([ImportError when importing psycopg2 on M1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71580859/importerror-when-importing-psycopg2-on-m1)), suggest installing psycopg2-binary, but that doesn't seem to work with sqlalchemy, b/c sqlalchemy calls psycopg2. any ideas?

Comment: `psycopg2-binary` will behave exactly the same as `psycopg2` i installed, you shouldn't need to make any code changes.  You'll need to uninstall `psycopg2` before installing though, to avoid possible confusion.